# process.env.SOME_KEY is undefined

Tags: node.js

How do I set the value of `process.env.SOME_KEY=some value` in the operating system and then read it in my node application?  I am running on Windows.

I tried these steps:

```
SET SOME_KEY=abc 
npm start
```

But when I try to read `process.env.SOME_KEY`, I am getting "undefined".

How do I set a env value and how do i read that in my code?

Comment: You can use cross-env - https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env

Comment: try this `SOME_KEY=abc npm start`

Comment: I just tried this and it worked fine for me.  Two things to try are (1) console.log(process.env) will show you all environment variables and (2) post your node code here so we can see exactly what's going on.

Answer (score 7):

Try this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

All you need to do is add a .env with your environment variables, and `require('dotenv').config()` as soon as you can in your application (the script called by npm start would be a good place)

Answer (score 1):

```
SOME_KEY=`${abc}` Fixed it for me.
```

Answer (score 0):

The npm module [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) was made exactly for this purpose. The way you set an environment variable is not same across all the OSes. `cross-env` solves this.

Else, you can also try `dotenv` that solves this with a `.env` file.

You can also do this at the very basic level:

```
process.env.SOME_KEY = "somevalue";
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in index file

```
require('dotenv').config({path: path.join(__dirname, '.env')});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const path = require('path');
require('dotenv').config( { path: path.join(__dirname, 'variables.env') });
```