# Why does NODE_ENV show undefined in my redux store when I use cross-env in package.json?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, package.json

Per research I've read that for cross platforms setting `NODE_ENV` is done better with [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) after reading:

- [process.env.NODE_ENV is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11104028/process-env-node-env-is-undefined)
- [NODE_ENV is showing undefined although i set environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48748461/node-env-is-showing-undefined-although-i-set-environment-variable)

after I've tried to use `set` and `export` in the *package.json* `scripts` but I still receive an 'undefined'. The combinations I've tried to set my `NODE_ENV` are:

*attempt 1 after research:*

```
"devDependencies": {
  "cross-env": "^7.0.2"
}

"scripts": {
  "dev-server": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server",
}
```

*attempt 2 from reading comments and answers:*

```
"scripts": {
  "dev-server": "set NODE_ENV=development&& webpack-dev-server",
}
```

*with:*

```
"scripts": {
  "dev-server": "set NODE_ENV=development && webpack-dev-server",
}
```

*and:*

```
"scripts": {
  "dev-server": "export NODE_ENV=development && webpack-dev-server",
}
```

but in my Redux store I continue to get `undefined`:

*configureStore.js:*

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from "redux";
  import fooReducer from "../reducers/foo";
  import barReducer from "../reducers/bar";
  
  const inDev =
    process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
      ? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ &&
        window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
      : "";
  
  export default () => {
    console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV);
  
    const store = createStore(
      combineReducers({
        foo: fooReducer,
        bar: barReducer,
      }),
      inDev
    );
  
    return store;
  };
```

terminal command I use is in VSC:

```
yarn run dev-server
```

The app works but a console log shows `undefined` and if the ternary is modified to `process.env.NODE_ENV === undefined` the extension works. Other Q&As I've read:

- [NodeJS environment variables undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56821291/nodejs-environment-variables-undefined)
- [process.env.SOME_KEY is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48932751/process-env-some-key-is-undefined)

Currently the app works but for some reason I cannot set `process.env.NODE_ENV` in *package.json* and the plugin tells me "No Store found" which is accurate because the `NODE_ENV` is undefined. How can I define within the script `dev-server` as a `NODE_ENV=development` in *package.json*?